# How can I make safe mp3 files for AVAudioPlayer, without getting errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have problem when trying to play some mp3 files on iOS app. 
First, I noticed that these files was also not working on Safari for iOS, but now I am having files that works on Safari for iOS, and doesn't work on my App.

I am using thi code to play mp3 audio files:

```
NSString *pronociationPath = …..

if (pronociationPath != nil) 
{           
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pronociationPath];
    NSError *error;

    self.player=[[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error] autorelease];
    [fileURL release];
    [self.player setNumberOfLoops:0];
    if (self.player == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
    else
    {
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

And I am having this error for a file that works on Safari iOS:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)"

Is something wrong with my code? 
Is there any guide to create safe mp3 files for iOS Apps ?
I've seen Apple documentation, but I don't see any useful informations https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW28

Comment: Are you using `pronociationPath` or `squarePronociationPath`?

Comment: @frowing I edited the post, We will say I am using pronociationPath, I verified that this file exist in simulator (I mean the path is OK), but return the error. If I change it with other file it works.

Comment: concerning my question " Is there any guide to create safe mp3 files for iOS Apps ?" I found that using audacity to export new mp3 file seems to be safe, with default configuration

Answer (score 5):

I also received same error (OSStatus error 1685348671) when I tried to play mp3 files on iOS 4.3.

Later on I found that it was the mp3 sound problem which made it incompatible to be played in iOS 4.3. So, I used iTunes Player to convert new version of mp3 sound with existing one. Now it works fine and better.

Steps:

1. Open your current mp3 sound in iTunes
2. Select it and Click on "Advanced" Menu >> "Create MP3 Version"

It wil create copy of current audio. Use newly created mp3 file for your app.

It helped me. I hope it might help others as well. All the best!

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. This fixed it for me. FYI, for other people running into this problem, you may need to change your import settings to default to MP3, otherwise you'll only see the "Create AAC Version" option. It's easy: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204310